# SDFormatter / Windows Crashes When Inserting Raspberri Pi SD Card

Tags: sd-card, retropie

I just received my first Raspberry Pi in the form of a [CanaKit Starter Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01C6Q2GSY). I was able to install Raspbian just fine, but wanted to install RetroPie instead.

Following some [instructions online](https://www.thegeekpub.com/4712/setting-retropie-raspberry-pi-3/), I downloaded and installed SDFormatter. However, when I inserted my MicroSD reader (with Raspberry Pi SD card) into my Windows 10 machine, it crashed instantly and needed to be restarted.

Upon restart, I inserted the reader again and it looked like Windows recognized it okay. However, SDFormatter freezes every time I try to launch it; it just never launches (though it shows running in Task Manager).

So I unplugged the reader and restarted. This time, I started SDFormatter first and it loaded up just fine. However, as soon as I plugged in the reader again, SDFormatter froze instantly (standard "Not Responding" message).

What could be going wrong here and how do I format the drive so I can install RetroPie?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the solution. I had Ext2FS installed in Windows so I could access my Linux partitions. Apparently this was causing issues. I uninstalled that, restarted, and proceeded with formatting the SD card without issue.